How can I avoid current excursion in P-channel MOSFET (high side) and BJT (low side) led matrix driver?
How can I avoid current excursion in combination of P-channel MOSFET (high side) and BJT (low side) led matrix driver? I have poor understanding of what causes the excursion and how to address it.
Here is my circuit:

.include sn74lvc1g14.cir

.model 2N3904 NPN(Is=6.734f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=74.03 Bf=416.4 Ne=1.259 Ise=6.734f Ikf=66.78m Xtb=1.5 Br=.7371 Nc=2 Isc=0 Ikr=0 Rc=1 Cjc=3.638p Mjc=.3085 Vjc=.75 Fc=.5 Cje=4.493p Mje=.2593 Vje=.75 Tr=239.5n Tf=301.2p Itf=.4 Vtf=4 Xtf=2 Rb=10)

.include tsm480p06cpr0g.cir

.subckt p_channel vlo ctl vhi
X0 vlo ctl vhi tsm480p06cpr0g
.ends

.model plain D(Is=0.0483p Rs=8.80 N=2.56)

D1 d1high d1low plain
Q1 d1low colres clamp 2N3904
R0 colctl colres 2.5k
R1 clamp 0 100ohm

Xbuf rowinv rowctl vxx 0 SN74LVC1G14
Xpch d1high rowinv vxx p_channel

vpsux vxx    0 PULSE(0   5 0.25m 0.10m 0.10m 1000m 1000m 0)
vpsuc colctl 0 PULSE(0 3.3 0.53m 0.01m 0.01m 0.06m  0.1m 0)
vpsur rowctl 0 PULSE(0 3.3 0.55m 0.01m 0.01m 0.02m  0.2m 0)

.save vxx colctl rowctl rowinv d1high d1low @D1[id]

.control
tran 0.0001m 1m
listing e > ./listing_e.txt
set hcopydevtype = svg
hardcopy plot1.svg vxx colctl rowctl rowinv d1high d1low d1high-d1low @D1[id]*1000
hardcopy plot2.svg vxx colctl rowctl rowinv d1high d1low d1high-d1low @D1[id]*100 xlimit 0.5582m 0.559m
.endc

And here are two plots, one showing the zoomed-out behavior and one that is zoomed in on the current excursion.


Update: I noticed the currents are lower than reasonable (should be around 100mA). Please consider R0 updated to 2.5k and R1 updated to 0ohm. The excursion remains (and appears in fact worse than before). New graphs:


Update2: It seems using R0=50ohm, R1=19ohm gets rid of most of the excursion. Still leaving this question open since it would be good to know the cause of it and whether the circuit can be modified to avoid it entirely, thereby being more robust to different resistor values.

I'd rather read a schematic than a netlist. (shoot thru? Slow turn-off of saturated BJT?)

I notice if I add a 5uH inductor and a 1N5819 flyback diode the excursion is gone and far wider range of values can be used for the resistances. Not sure if this is the best approach but empirically it seems to work.
